# gem install on bundle folder (vendor/bundle)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install a ruby project, which has a dependency like in Gemfile

```
nokogiri (1.6.1)
```

bundlr fails

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I followed the [instructions](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) to install nokogiri manually and succeeded (OSX 10.9.2)

```
 which nokogiri
/usr/bin/nokogiri
nokogiri
Nokogiri: an HTML, XML, SAX, and Reader parser
Usage: nokogiri <uri|path> [options] ...
```

but, how can I install nokogiri to the expected path by the app (vendor/bundle , like the other dependencies, not in system folder). I tried an option `--path vendor/bundle` with `gem install`, but  it is not recognized

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I am running gem install as another user, that is why no permission to write to system folder. still, it is not trying to install at `vendor/bundle`.

It is also ok if I can find a way to use bundle (instead of gem) to install nokogiri. But, I am not sure how to specify the dependencies like the installation command below.

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 
                        --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
                        --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
                        --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                        --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create config for bundler in `~/.bundle/config`:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: ./vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_BUILD__NOKOGIRI: --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 
                        --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib 
                        --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 
                        --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include 
                        --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

and after `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. also had to export env variable NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1

Answer (score 0):

On Mac I have tried the following and it worked.

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```